# is it possible to set a variable at a global level such that we dont have to pass the parameter down the chain in coffescript?

Tags: javascript, function, coffeescript, nested

```
    class D
         func4:() -> 
                console.log(x) # x is not parameter to this function
    class C
        constructor: (@d = new D) ->
        func3:() => 
            @d.func4()

    class B
        constructor: (@c = new C) ->
        func2:() => 
            @c.func3()

    class A
        constructor: (@b = new B) ->
        func1:(x=10) -> 
            @b.func2()
    a = new A
    a.func1()

a = new A
a.func1() or a.func1(10) # want the x value to be printed as 10 instead it prints undefined.
```

I want the x value to be printed without actually passing it as a parameter down the chain all the way to `func4`.

Is that possible in coffescript? Any sort of hack would also help, I just don't want to pass `x` as a parameter down the chain because there are many function calls down the chain.

The code above is a sample. Hints would be similar to thread local in java.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must use global variables, there is workaround way to set them to a global scope in coffee-script.

Via the [Docs](http://coffeescript.org/):

> If you'd like to create top-level variables for other scripts to use,
>   attach them as properties on window, or on the exports object in
>   CommonJS. The existential operator (covered below), gives you a
>   reliable way to figure out where to add them, if you're targeting both
>   CommonJS and the browser: root = exports ? this

```
global = exports ? this
global.x = 10
```

You can also cheat with backticks.

```
`x= 10`
```

will compile to `x= 10;` however the backticks will mess with coffee-scripts ability to understand x as a variable preconversion, so it's not advisable.

Comment: I dont have to use global if there is a better workaround than actually passing x down the chain. I just cannot pass it down the chain coz there are many levels deep.

Comment: Try the code and report back if you have additional questions or worries =)

Comment: can you tell me where exactly I should put those lines. every class that I mentioned above starts with the following line module.exports = class A ; module.exports = class B and so on. Also this is all in the backened so there is no window object or anything

Comment: Please read the docs. If it is backend (node etc.) use exports with the this keyword. If your class starts by initializing export globals then you can put the variable x in the same spot.

Comment: I read the docs however I couldn't find anything useful to my question. and yes it is node.js

Comment: Both the docs and my answer above answer your question. For a global variable declare it as an export. `global = exports ? this global.x = 10`